# moodle email configuration error

Tags: email, authentication, configuration, outlook, moodle

I have been trying to **configure SMTP** in order to send an confirmation email to **email based self-registration** users but each time an error message appear saying that

> ***Tried to send you an email but failed!***

[this is my moodle email configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgAMS.png)

[this is the error message I get when I run a test email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V73lY.png)

when searched the error I found that ***Moodle does not connect to email server.***

is there any other configurations that I should check?

---

since this did not work I tried to connect through **outlook**.

I tried to configure outlook but it also failed.

[this is the configuration for outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sODlA.png)

[this is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrAVG.png)

please help..!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, we are using our own mailserver..
However, there are some restrictions to Gmail usage, which can require you to make some changes on your Gmail account.

Have a look at this to allow a new service access to your Gmail account:
https://www.lifewire.com/unlock-gmail-for-a-new-email-program-or-service-1171974

And here to allow your Gmail access to less secure services and programs:
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1